# Joining two tables together strictly by order

Tags: sql

If I have two tables(t1, t2), each with one column

```
t1      
letters  
a         
b         
c         

t2
nums
1
2
3
```

Is it possible to "join" the two together in a way that produces a two-column result set that looks like this:

```
letters nums
a       1
b       2
c       3
```

Requirements for the solution:

- Must combine each table's data in a specified order, so being able
  to order each table's data before joining
- Doesn't use any functions, like row_number, to add an extra column to join on

Bonus points:
 - If two tables have different row counts, final result set is count of the max of the two tables, and the "missing" data is nulls.

Just wondering if this is possible given the constraints.

Comment: create table t3 as select * from t1, t2;

Comment: select * from t1, t2 order by desc;

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: It would be easy with `row_number()`, but without... I can't think of a way off the top of my head. The tables need *something* in common that can be joined on. Maybe in a stored procedure and not straight up SQL...

Comment: @OmidCompSCI did you try those?

Comment: @Shawn me neither!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen keeping the version agnostic as I'm curious if there is a pure standard SQL way to do this. If someone posts an answer that applies to only one version they can state that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `row_number()`.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column that specifies the ordering.

The idea is:

```
select l.letter, n.number
from (select l.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from letters l
     ) l join
     (select n.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from numbers n
     ) n
     on l.seqnum = n.seqnum;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

If you want all rows in both tables, use `full join` rather than an inner join.

EDTI:

`row_number()` is the obvious solution, but you can do this with a correlated subquery assuming the values are unique:

```
select l.letter, n.number
from (select l.*, 
             (select count(*) from letters l2 where l2.letter <= l.letter) as seqnum
      from letters l
     ) l join
     (select n.*, 
             (select count(*) from numbers n2 where n2.num <= n.num) as seqnum
      from numbers n
     ) n
     on l.seqnum = n.seqnum;
```

I find the restriction on not using `row_number()` to be rather absurd, given that it is an ISO/ANSI standard function supported by almost all databases.

Comment: Correct, my question prohibits use of a function

Comment: I am upvoting this as being the only general answer assuming the two columns have nothing in common (other than an overall order between each one).

Comment: And make it a FULL OUTER JOIN to collect the bonus.  BTW this operation is sometimes called Zip, by analogy with a zipper.

Comment: It was downvoted because the question literally called out row_number as prohibited, and your original answer used row_number.  I asked this question to get at a particular scenario.

Your edit does achieve the required result, so I'll happily convert the downvote to upvote now. :)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I almost titled this "zipping" but I thought it would imply I wanted to interleave the rows from each table into one column of the resultset.

Answer (score 2):

If your version of SQL supports an ASCII function (which can generate an ASCII code for each lowercase letter), then you may join on the ASCII code shifted downwards by 96:

```
SELECT
    t1.letters,
    t2.nums
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.nums = ASCII(t1.letters) - 96;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Clever, but the letters/numbers data is just for illustration. Real data is more complex

Comment: @JoshDiehl Without an ASCII function, to convert the letters to numbers, or `ROW_NUMBER`, you can't really answer your question.